# looping through LI's using Each function

Tags: jquery, html

Hey guys i am quite a newbie to JQuery.
i have this dilemma, i am unable to loop throguh each Li's using each.
Actually i am making a slider and i have these thumbs i li.
Now what i've one is ive coded that on each LI click the action happens.
Now i wanna make the slider automatic by click on thumbs through loop with time. 
 here is my thumb code

```
  <ul id="thumbsList">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

Now here is my jquery each function

```
    $( "# li" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).click();
});
```

Now it runs ok but runs only once.
How can i loop this with a time constrainet say after every one second next li click. thanks.

Comment: you need to use a delay in the loop

Comment: can you make a  code commit please. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
var $lis = $('#thumbsList li'),
    index = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    $lis.eq(index).click();
    index = ++index % $lis.length;
}, 1000)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v8LNs/)

Comment: Thanks but there is this one question, i want to run it on document ready function after first slide like from second for the first time as first slide is already there. should i set index to 1 right?